# Comma Notation Meaning in Fuzzy Logic Statement

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I have the following statement;

$$
(A \cup B)_\alpha = A_\alpha \cup B_\alpha, (A \cap B)_\alpha = A_\alpha \cap B_\alpha
$$

The minimum and maximum operators represent the intersection and union of the fuzzy sets.

$A_\alpha$ is defined as;

$$A_\alpha = \{x \in X | \mu_\alpha(x) \geq \alpha\}$$

Similar idea for $B_\alpha$.

I am not sure what the comma means between the two halves of the central statement? Appreciate any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is  a comma as used in everyday English, used to separate clauses / statements. Nothing specific to math.

> It rained today, and I bought a hat.
>
> $(A \cup B)_\alpha$ equals $A_\alpha \cup B_\alpha$, and  $(A \cap B)_\alpha$ equals $A_\alpha \cap B_\alpha$.

Comment: Aw c'mon, fuzzy logic likes to re-define everything. Surely this fuzzy comma has some probabilistic nature above and beyond a regular comma. ;-}

Comment: Thanks for the help! Doesn't that then imply it could be replaced by an $=$ then? If that is the case, I think the statement doesn't make sense, becuase; $$A_\alpha \cup B_\alpha \neq A_\alpha \cap B_\alpha$$?

Comment: Sorry! I have just understood what you mean... It is two seperate statements just next to each other on the line.... Just didn't see it for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!